Any efficient way to create a heatmap matrix?
Given a set of coordination and values like
coors=np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]])
heat_values=[3,2,1]

I would like to generate a matrix like
mtx=[[3,0,0],
     [0,2,0],
     [0,0,1]]

Any functions can do the jobs?

See scipy.sparse.  This is the right solution if you use a very large matrix.

I would use numpy.zeros and indexing:
mtx = np.zeros(coors.max(0)+1, dtype=int)
mtx[tuple(coors.T)] = heat_values

Output:
array([[3, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])

NB. if heat_values is an array, better use dtype=heat_values.dtype.
This should generalize to any dimension of coors:
coors=np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,1],[0,2,3]])
heat_values=[9,8,7]
             
mtx = np.zeros(coors.max(0)+1, dtype=int)
mtx[tuple(coors.T)] = heat_values

array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 8, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 7]],

       [[9, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]])

If you want to force a "square" output:
coors=np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[2,3]])
heat_values=[1,2,3]
             
mtx = np.zeros((np.max(coors)+1,)*coors.shape[1], dtype=int)
mtx[tuple(coors.T)] = heat_values

array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])


Create an array filled with zeros with the appropriate shape, then populate it with the values in the specified coordinates:
coors = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]])
heat_values = [3, 2, 1]

mtx = np.zeros((coors[:, 0].max() + 1, coors[:, 1].max() + 1))
mtx[coors[:, 0], coors[:, 1]] = heat_values

[[3. 0. 0.]
 [0. 2. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]


import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

# Given coordinates and values
coors = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]])
heat_values = [3, 2, 1]

# Determine the size of the matrix
matrix_size = np.max(coors, axis=0) + 1

# Create the CSR matrix
csr_matrix = csr_matrix(
(heat_values, (coors[:, 0], coors[:, 1])  )
, shape=matrix_size)

dense_matrix = csr_matrix.toarray()
'''
[[3 0 0]
 [0 2 0]
 [0 0 1]]
'''

